# Transform string using transformation rules from substrings

Tags: c, string

Say I have a string like this: `aaaaaa`

And I have a transformation that needs to be applied that looks like this: `aa -> b`

My question is:

1. How would I find all substrings (separately) that are the result of applying the transformation rule to each of the substrings in the given string. So, for example, in the case that I put as an example, I would need to get the following resulting strings:

   baaaa,
   abaaa,
   aabaa,
   aaaba,
   aaaab

Comment: If you have two questions, you should post them as seperate questions.

Comment: Uh... you don't want to apply the transformation for all matches at once, but you want seperate result strings for all matches?

Comment: Yes, I want separate result strings, actually in new strings. I don't want any replacements in the original string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step through the string by incrementing a char*. Every time you have stepped forward in the string, use strncmp to check whether the wanted substring (e.g. aa) follows. Each time it is true, duplicate the string and replace the string you're looking for in the copy:

```
// str is the string
// needle is what you want to replace
// replacement is what you want to replace the needle with
for (char *p = str; *p != '\0'; p++) {
  if (strncmp(p, needle, strlen(needle)) == 0) {
    char *str_ = malloc(strlen(str)+1+strlen(replacement)-strlen(needle));
    strcpy(str_, str);
    char *p_ = p - str + str_;
    memmove(p_+strlen(replacement), p_+strlen(needle), strlen(p_)+1-strlen(replacement));
    memcpy(p_, replacement, strlen(replacement));
    // do something with str_ here (and probably free it at some point)
  }
}
```